# Adapting borders for a select2 when there is too much options

Tags: html, jquery-select2

A picture says more than long explainations, here's my probleme :

[image]

As you can see in the pic, when too many options are selected with the select2 modal, it goes out of borders and give this ugly displaying.

Here is the source code of the select2 :

```
 <div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Liste des metiers</label>
         <div class="col-sm-9">
             <select class="select2 form-control" multiple="multiple" style="height: 36px;width: 100%;" id="metiers">
             <?php foreach ($metiers as $metier) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $metier['nom_metier'] ?>" <?php if (isset($entreprise_metiers[$metier['nom_metier']])) echo ('selected') ?>><?php echo $metier['nom_metier'] ?></option>
             <?php } ?>

             </select>
         </div>
```

So, if you guys have a solution for this, I'll gratefully take it

Comment: without exact code we cant help you?

Comment: Please remove `php` tag

Comment: php tag removed, this is the only code of the select2 row you see on the picture. The other parts are initializing variables, which is useless to show in this case.